# Container part identification

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Please help me identify the set this part belongs to, we are going through three tons of bricks and try to put the sets together again... [image]

Answer (score 12):

That looks like [Container, X-Pod Barrel Section 10 x 10 x 3 1/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47674#T=C), which were used to store bricks for [X-Pod sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=623).

[image]

Such container was available in Trans-Red in single set [4415, Auto Pod](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4415-1)

[image]

And [4417, Aero Pod](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4417-1) was the only set to use it Trans-Yellow

[image]

Comment: Great picture choices help make this a really good answer.